# Canvas snake bug event

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have made a snake game but when for example im going right and click down & left at the same time it kill think it collided with itself and die.

the code for the eventing is:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

var key = e.which;

if(key == "37" && dir!= "right") dir = "left";
else if (key == "38" && dir != "down") dir = "up";
else if (key == "39" && dir != "left") dir = "right";
else if (key == "40" && dir != "up") dir = "down";



})
```

I have this code inside a paint method that gets repainted every 60ms

```
var headX = snakeArray[0].x;
var headY = snakeArray[0].y;

//directions
if (dir == "right") headX++;
else if (dir == "left") headX--;
if(dir =="up") headY--;
else if (dir == "down") headY++;


//game over clause
if (headX == -1 || headX == w/cellSize || headY == -1 || headY == h/cellSize ||     CheckCollision(headX,headY, snakeArray))
{
//restart game
init();
return;
}
```

To test the game yourself:
http://www.taffatech.com/Snake.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is no bug.

The timestep between every frame is so big, that you can easily generate two keydown function calls within one frame.

-> That causes that your snake goes at first (e.g.) right, then gets a "down" keypressing, changes its direction to "down" and then gets a "left" keypressing before it gets moved. So your snake "turns 180 degrees" in one frame and literally eats itself.

You should ensure to just accept one single new direction in one frame and (to better up the gameplay) queue the other pressed keys to compute their affects in the following frames.

Comment: Do you know what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: I would take a list called "keyqueue" or something and would append one element that holds the pressed direction everytime a button gets pressed. Then in every renderstep I would release the first element from the list (if the list isn't empty) and do the thing with it, that you did in the keypressfunction. Thats all.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt do what you said but instead used a variable boolean that is false or true based on if you can move and only lets 1 move per frame. Thanks it works!

Comment: still you should remember that some players press many buttons in a very short timespan particularly if the snake is already very long. then every keypress has to be used and cannot simply be "erased" as you do it now. if you want a really playable game, queue the buttonpresses :D

Comment: But wouldnt that lead to error when the snake is slow, Like if people pressed loads fast then the snake would act like it is on autopilot? moving on its own to their eyes?

Comment: yes that is true. you should do what you think fits best. i would queue at least 2 directions